# I am unable to log in on Android Stack Overflow app with my existing account email

Tags: bug, android-app

I am unable to log in on the Android Stack Overflow app with my existing email id, so I created an account using sign up with the Stack Exchange option with the same email if got confirm email mail, but it's not confirming the account as it already exist, so how do I log in with the Android app?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have happened due to your only login on this account being Yahoo OpenID, and the app not supporting all the OpenID services the web supports yet.

We'll be adding a "Login with OpenID" option into the app to fix this.

Until then, you'll need to add a Stack Exchange login to your account on [your settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/360371) on the website. After that you'll be able to login with the username and password in the app.